# No tab bar or application menu or Unity

Tags: 11.04

I just had a notification that a new version of Ubuntu pop up today, and after looking at some screen shots, I decided to give it a try.  After I installed it and rebooted, the Top and bottom bar are gone, leaving only the desktop.  I can use the links on the desktop (that's how I started my browser), but the application's menu is gone.  How do I fix it?

EDIT:

If I run `unity` from bash, it seems to work alright.  There still is no tab bar at the bottom, I don't know if that's normal for unity.

Answer (score 1):

Have a go at logging out from the system. Then when you choose your user at the bottom of the screen you can choose a different session. Try ubuntu-classic and see if you get the panels back. I had a similar problem when playing around with compiz. To solve it opened up the compiz manager, choose preferences, from the drop down chose unity then hit the "Reset to defaults" button.

Either way, to access a terminal without panels double click a folder on your desktop (if you have one). Then navigate yourself to /usr/share/applications. In there you should find Terminal.

Hope some of the above stuff helps.

Answer (score 0):

No "bottom bar" is normal for Unity. It has been replaced by the 'launcher', located on the left border of the screen by default.